# MVC 5 can't loop through a List within a List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an XML document that I'm reading though to create a List of objects and inside of that object is another list of objects. What I can't figure out how to do is loop through the secondary list.

I have a list of Newsletters that I'm grouping together by Year. The first list is a list of all the years (ex: 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015) and then inside of the years is another list of actual Newsletters.

I can do the loop through the list of Years but can't find a way to loop through the list of Newsletters for that year.

I'm trying to do something like this in my View but the NewsletterList is not seen.

```
@foreach (var year in Model.NewsletterYearList)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.NewsletterYearList.NewsletterList)
    {

    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
   public class NewsletterViewModel
    {
        public List<NewsletterYear> NewsletterYearList;
    }

    public class NewsletterYear
    { 
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public List<Newsletter> NewsletterList; 
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of Model (I'm only doing 3 months for 3 years for development purposes). 
[image]

Comment: `foreach (var item in Model.NewsletterYearList.NewsletterList)`, didn't you mean to use `foreach (var item in year.NewsletterList)`?

Comment: No, the NewsletterYearList is a list for all the Lists for each year. The property Year is just there so I know which year I'm dealing with.

Comment: You need to try the code in @CamiloTerevinto comment (which is correct)

Comment: Intellisense doesn't show Model.NewsletterYearList.Newsletterlist. I'm not seeing what I'm doing that's keeping it from seeing the second list.

Comment: I see you have solved your issue, but didn't `Model.NewsletterYearList.NewsletterList` give you a build error? As clearly `NewsletterList` isn't a property of `NewsletterYearList` (it is a property of each element of the list, no the list itself, it's like doing `PeopleList.Age`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your your model, your code should be :-

```
  @foreach (var year in Model.NewsletterYearList)
  {
        // we have a year, and year contains all the newsletters for this year
        // so lets loop through the newsletters....
        foreach (var item in year.NewsletterList)
        {
             // item is the newsletter...
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is going to work. Starring at so many things that start with the word Newsletter it gets a little confusing but after I looked at it for a couple minutes it makes sense. I'll work with it more tomorrow but this looks like what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

According tom your model construction your looping structure should be like this

```
@if(Model != null && Model.NewsletterYearList.Count >0){
   foreach(var year in Model.NewsletterYearList.Count){
      // Already we had reference of single item of
      // Model.NewsletterYearList variable in 'year'
      // So directly use variable 'year' in next iteration
     foreach(var newsletter in year.NewsletterList){
        // Your business logic
     }

   }
}
```